# the set of points equidistant from $ u $ and $v$ form a line.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces, euclidean-geometry

Let $u$ and $v$ be two vectors in $ \mathbb{R}^2 $ with the standard norm. Show that the set of points equidistant from $ u $ and $v$ form a line.

I show that if $x$ is equidistant from $u$ and $v$, then for all  $\gamma$ $\in$ $ \mathbb{R} $ $\gamma $$x$ to be equidistant from  $ u $ and $v$.$\gamma $$x$ form a  line. Unfortunately I can't show any vector $a$ that is equidistant from $ u $ and $v$  in the line  $\gamma$$x$.

Comment: Hint:think in terms of bisector of the angle between the vectors $u$ and $v$.

Comment: @AnuragA you mean i need to think line \gamma x as a bisector of the angle between the vectors u and v and what ? How can it help me to show $a$ is in this line ,in terms of coordinates ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you don't want equal *constant* distance, but equal normal distance *at any point*. At this point of time it is more beneficial to consider how equations of angle bisector(s) are derived in analytic geometry.

but how can i say all points that is equidistant from u and v will be on this line ? –rmznyzgyr

EDIT1:
@rmznyzgyr: Good question. Remember, distance between a point and a line refers only to the *minimum* distance between them, but not *any* or *all* distances. This terminology is a geometrical convention.

EDIT2:

[Equal Normal Distance](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1366&bih=609&q=angle%20bisector&oq=angle%20bisector&gs_l=img.1.0.0l10.46251.46251.2.48334.1.0.1.0.1.0.0.0..0.0.msedrc...0...1ac..56.img..4.12.1829.hBEUyIVzzrQ#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=a-_6S-tkBw98zM%253A%3BaVAiZojLGf3bAM%3Bhttps%253A%252F%252Fdr282zn36sxxg.cloudfront.net%252Fdatastreams%252Ff-d%25253Ab16d16a05b6063491fb06c0f15399081e4c42b929a25efd3857bb776%25252BIMAGE%25252BIMAGE.1%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.ck12.org%252Fgeometry%252FAngle-Bisectors-in-Triangles%252Flesson%252FAngle-Bisectors-in-Triangles---Intermediate%252F%3B594%3B610)

DE = DF at any point on the internal (or external) bisector of given angle included between u and v.

For unit vectors  $u = e^\alpha $  and $v = e^\beta$ ... the vector $ e^{(\alpha+\beta)/2} $ is the bisector.

Comment: but how can i say all points that is equidistant from u and v will be on this line ?

Comment: @rmznyzgyr: That is a good point.

Comment: @Narashimham i can't see the connection between distance between a point and a line and my question Could you be more clear please ?

Answer (score 1):

Difference of squares!
\begin{align*}
\|x-u\|=\|x-v\|
&\iff \|x-u\|^2 - \|x-v\|^2 = 0 \\
&\iff \langle x-u+x-v, x-u-x+v\rangle = 0 \\
&\iff \langle x-\tfrac{u+v}{2}, v-u\rangle = 0
\end{align*}
So $x$ is equidistant from $u$ and $v$ if and only if the vector from $\frac{u+v}{2}$ to $x$ is perpendicular to the vector from $u$ to $v$.  At this point you can supply a geometric argument that the set of such $x$ forms a line; alternatively, you can rewrite the above condition as
$$ (v-u)^T x = (v-u)^T\tfrac{u+v}{2} $$
which is a matrix equation $Ax=b$ with $A$ being $1\times 2$ and not zero (assuming $u\ne v$).  General considerations about linear systems will tell you that the solutions of such an equation form a line.